# how to merge 2 excel files with the same name in different folders?

Tags: python

```
   from collections import defaultdict
from glob import glob
from itertools import chain, groupby
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint, pformat
from textwrap import indent
import os
import os.path
ca_2015= "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\Canada 2015"
ca_2016= "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\Canada 2016"
ca_2017= "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\Canada 2017"
ca_2018= "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\Canada 2018"
ca_2019= "D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\Canada 2019"
files_2015 = os.listdir(ca_2015)
files_2016 = os.listdir(ca_2016)
files_2017 = os.listdir(ca_2017)
files_2018 = os.listdir(ca_2018)
files_2019 = os.listdir(ca_2019)
df_total= pd.DataFrame()

i=0
for file in files_2017:
    os.chdir("D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\Canada 2017")
    if file in files_2018 and file in files_2019:
        df_file= pd.read_csv(file)
        df_total= pd.concat([df_file], ignore_index=True)
        for f in files_2018:
            os.chdir("D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\Canada 2018")
            if f in files_2017 and f in files_2019:
                df_f= pd.read_csv(f)
                df_total= pd.concat([df_f], ignore_index=True)
                for ffile in files_2019:
                    os.chdir("D:\master concordia\DYD\Ecobee DYD\canada\Canada 2019")
                    if ffile in files_2017 and f in files_2018:
                        df_ffile= pd.read_csv(ffile)
                        df_total= pd.concat([df_ffile], ignore_index=True)
                        df_total.to_csv(("thermostat"+str(i)+".csv"),(output_folder))
                        i +=1
```

I'm trying to write a code to combine 5 excel files with the same name but in different folders, this is what I got so far the problem is it only read the first file, can someone please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: @stovfl I want to concat 5 excel files in 5 different folders, I was just trying the 1st 2 files to see if it will work

Comment: Look at this simulation, would this meet your requirements : [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/IrresponsibleDimgrayKeys)